# A small query regarding appcelerator titanium?

Tags: mobile, cross-platform, mobile-website, titanium, appcelerator

i'm planning on working with titanium.

i want to know if "[Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)" can be eliminated by using titanium.

are there any drawbacks in titanium?

please recommend some cross-platforms..

please do leave some suggestions..

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOP is especially used for HTTP. So it doesn't concern titanium since it only use javascript as "local" language that is "translated" into xcode. at the end you got an simple xcode-project and an .app file.

i use it for a quite complex app and it works fine. i needed adding some features as module written in objC since the framework isn't as ongoing concering the iphone API as the native objC, but that worked out fine.

Comment: Thank you for your view man. here is my id: (prateekraj.dasari(at)gmail.com) hope you hit me back thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are asking for the drawbacks of Titanium.. here it is..

1. I would not say that it's cross platform. Even my android app will look different in my Mac compared to the one developed in Windows.
2. Not all functions will work on Android and iPhone. Some will partially work on the other.
   Ti is a biased and Android Developer are always left behind.
3. Also, if you are developing an Android app like me, you will be facing a lot of problems and Kitchen Sink will not always work. Android development in Ti is very bad and expect to find a lot of bugs.
4. Contacts API is not even complete as of now (Version 1.60) . I can't even get the contacts email and phone number!
5. No Bluetooth support
6. I spent a lot of hours "debugging" and waiting for the emulator rather than serious coding.
   API refence and the QA will help a bit but there are more questions than answers.
7. Ti doesn't even have a proper debugging features as well as IDE. Make sure to dedicate a lot of hours in knowing how it works. I have a hard time finding a good resources to start.
8. Memory Problem and Leaks are very common.
9. Gradients will not work in Android (use image instead)
10. and last thing, Documentation really sucks!

(but still I love Ti despite all of the above)